# ResourceDictionary in application resources cannot be found

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, resourcedictionary, staticresource

I'm facing some strange issue with a ResourceDictionary in my Application.Resources.
In order to fill multiple ComboBoxes inside my application, I want to store the data in a ResourceDictionary.

However, I get the "Cannot find a Resource with that Name/Key..." error constantly.

My XAML-Code here:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="RDArray">
        <sys:String x:Key="item1">Item1</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="item2">Item2</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="item3">Item3</sys:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding Values, Source={StaticResource RDArray}}" />
```

Due to some lucky circumstances I was able to find out that putting another resource like Style **above** the Dictionary solves the problem.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="fubar" />
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="RDArray">
        <sys:String x:Key="item1">Item1</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="item2">Item2</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="item3">Item3</sys:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The "bug" occurs in a WPF application as well as in Silverlight.

Although I can solve this using the shown "trick", I am curious where this error is coming from. I wasn't able to find anything about this. Maybe it is just me and something I am understanding wrong about resources in WPF.

Comment: You may want to use the [x:Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752340.aspx) markup extension instead. That allows you to define lists of items in XAML.

Answer (score 4):

This is because if you have a resource dictionary as the only item in the resources section then the contents simply get added to the parent dictionary (I [snooped](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and this seems to be the case).  To get around this you need to put your resource dictionary in separate xaml file (List.xaml in this case):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="RDArray">
        <sys:String x:Key="item1">Item1</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="item2">Item2</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="item3">Item3</sys:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and then reference that in your main app:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="List.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding Values, Source={StaticResource RDArray}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
In my real application I created that separated file, but I didn't make a second ResourceDictionary inside of it a nd just put the string values there. So it looked like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <sys:String x:Key="item1">Item1</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="item2">Item2</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="item3">Item3</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So this was of course not working either.

Thanks for your answer, definitely solves this one.

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked - Quick point for the future - you need to mark the answer as accepted and your 'answer' should be a comment on mine.    Its not the same as a forum :)